# consumer class not writing to list Multi threaded application Java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, consumer

I am having a problem with this consumer class.
When i run the program i get an out of bounds exception with each thread in the pool.
I have sysout the list size and it is zero for some reason.
Please see my code below.
I'ts something to with the list being set but i cant figure it out.
Every other part of the program is working and tested just this last part is giving me problems.
Any help offered would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue<Shingle> q;
    private int k;
    private int[] minHashes;
    private Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    private ExecutorService pool;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Shingle> q, int k, int poolSize) {
        super();
        this.q = q;
        this.k = k;
        pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        Random random = new Random();
        minHashes = new int[k];
        for (int i = 0; i < minHashes.length; i++) {
            minHashes[i] = random.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        try {
            int docCount = 2;
            while (docCount > 0) {
                Shingle s = q.take();
                if (s instanceof Poision) {
                    docCount--;
                } else {
                    pool.execute( new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            for (int i = 0; i < minHashes.length; i++) {
                                int value = s.getHashCode() ^ minHashes[i]; // ^ - xor(Random generated key)
                                List<Integer> list = map.get(s.getDocId());
                                if (list == null) {
                                    list = new ArrayList<Integer>(k);
                                    for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                                        list.set(j , Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                                    }
                                    map.put(s.getDocId(), list);
                                } else {
                                    if (list.get(i) > value) {
                                        list.set(i, value);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that this line

```
list = new ArrayList<Integer>(k);
```

create list with **initial capacity** equal to k not with **size** equal to k. So your list has 0 elements and the for loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
   list.set(j , Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

doesn't execute any iteration. You then add empty list to the map and because of that `list.get(i)` throws exception.

Please change your for loop to

```
for (int j = 0; j < minHashes.length; j++) {
    list.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

to actually add elements to list.